# Highchart bar chart start bar from centre instead of left

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, bar-chart

I am using highchart bar chart and removed x and y axis. Here I want start my chart from centre with equally have padding/margin from left and right.

[image]

Comment: here is my chart code https://jsfiddle.net/2b613k8e/

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this approach:

```
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    events: {
      render() {
        let chart = this;
        if (chartForRender) {
          chartForRender = false;
          chart.update({
            chart: {
              marginLeft: chart.chartWidth / 2
            }
          })
        }
        chartForRender = true;
      }
    }
  },
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/49oxesdh/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

Comment: is it possible for provide marginLeft for each data bar? for example 1st bar has 65 marginLeft, 2nd has 60 marginLeft, 3rd has 25 and last one has 20 marginLeft.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible, however, you should be able to achieve a similar visual effect by using the `columnrange` series: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/columnrange